# How to create attribute for Underline on UILabel?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsattributedstring

I already have this attribute on my code, but how to add attribute for underline?

```
NSDictionary *attrs = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: 
boldFont, NSFontAttributeName, foregroundColor, NSForegroundColorAttributeName, nil];
```

Comment: All the keys are listed in  the NSAttributedString UIKit Additions Reference.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just add a `NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName` key with `@(NSUnderlineStyleSingle)` as a value:

```
NSDictionary *attrs = @{ NSFontAttributeName : boldFont, 
                         NSForegroundColorAttributeName : foregroundColor,
                         NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName : @(NSUnderlineStyleSingle) };
```